# Дискорд Бот, который мониторит изменение в txt файле и отправляет в последнюю строку изменения из файла

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть код, который мониторит изменения на сайте и записывает новую строку с изменениями на сайте в txt файл. Мне нужно, чтобы при добавлении новой строки в файл, бот отправлял эту строку в дискорд. Добавление новой строки происходит не постоянно.

Пробовал сравнивать строки в файле, а также выводить результат по времени. Но при изменении файла сравнение происходило не по последним строкам, а по тем, что были при запуске. Вывод с таймером также не подходит. Вот код, который у меня вышел.

```
import discord
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import time

client = discord.Client()

x = 0
with open('botfile.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
    x = x + 1

x1 = x - 1
x2 = x - 2
abc = list()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  with open('botfile.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        abc.append(line)
    last_mess = abc[x1]
    pre_mess = abc[x2]
    print(last_mess, pre_mess)
    if last_mess != pre_mess:
      await message.channel.send(last_mess)
      time.sleep(15)



async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
keep_alive()   
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))


async def on_message():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id_here')
    while not client.is_closed:
        counter += 1
        await message.channel.send(channel, counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для реализации вашей идеи достаточно всего одной функции. Сделаем ее командой бота. Для этого, вместо объекта `discord.Client()`, предлагаю использовать `discord.ext.commands.Bot()`, который помимо функций клиента, умеет также обрабатывать команды, начинающиеся с указанного префикса (в данном случае с "**!**").

Создадим команду `async def write_from_txt(ctx)` и пометим ее сверху соответствующим декоратором `bot.command()`, чтобы дискорд понимал, что эта функция - команда бота.

При вызове этой команды будем вызывать бесконечный цикл `while True`, в котором каждые 3 секунды будем открывать файл `botfile.txt` на чтение и считывать его отдельные строки в массив. Затем проверим, совпадает ли последняя строка файла с предыдущей последней строкой, и если нет - то отправим ее содержимое в канал, а переменную с последней строкой перезапишем на новую.

Для возможности остановки команды, добавим условие, при котором, если последняя строка файла равна *"break"*, цикл будет прерываться и команда остановится.

**[ ! ]** Задержка в 3 секунды нужна для того, чтобы слишком сильно не загружать процессор открытием файла.

**Код:**

```
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def write_from_txt(ctx):
    last_text = ''
    while True:
        with open('botfile.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
            text = file.readlines()
            file.close()
        if text[-1] == 'break':
            await ctx.send('Выполнение функции `write_from_txt()` прервано!')
            break
        if last_text != text[-1]:
            last_text = text[-1]
            await ctx.send(text[-1])
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```